# How to launch cefsimple in fullscreen mode?

Tags: linux, browser, fullscreen, chromium-embedded

I want to launch cefsimple application (as cef smaple project) in fullscreen mode on Ubuntu 20.04.

Downloaded cef from [Spotify AutoBuild](https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html), then added code into OnWindowCreated or OnAfterCreated in cefsimple project. But it seems not work. Does anyone have a good thought? Thanks.

```cpp
/* simple_app.cc */

class SimpleWindowDelegate : public CefWindowDelegate {
 public:
  explicit SimpleWindowDelegate(CefRefPtr<CefBrowserView> browser_view)
      : browser_view_(browser_view) {}

  void OnWindowCreated(CefRefPtr<CefWindow> window) override {
    // Add the browser view and show the window.
    window->AddChildView(browser_view_);
    window->Show();

    // BEG: added
    window->SetFullscreen(true);
    // END

    // Give keyboard focus to the browser view.
    browser_view_->RequestFocus();
  }
```

```cpp
/* simple_handler.cc */

void SimpleHandler::OnAfterCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  // Add to the list of existing browsers.
  browser_list_.push_back(browser);

  // BEG: added
  CefRefPtr<CefBrowserView> browser_view = CefBrowserView::GetForBrowser(browser);
  if (browser_view) {
    CefRefPtr<CefWindow> window = browser_view->GetWindow();
    if (window) {
      window->SetFullscreen(true);
    }
  }
  // END
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to make the window fullscreen. In the end what I did was to maximize the window via X11 API.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

void makeBrowserWindowFullscreen(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
    auto xDisplay = cef_get_xdisplay();
    auto xWindow = browser->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle();

    int screen_number = DefaultScreen(xDisplay);
    auto display_width = DisplayWidth(xDisplay, screen_number);
    auto display_height = DisplayHeight(xDisplay, screen_number);
    XResizeWindow(xDisplay, xWindow, display_width * 2, display_height * 2);
    XMoveWindow(xDisplay, xWindow, 0, 0);
    XFlush(xDisplay);
  }
}
```

Then, simply call `makeBrowserWindowFullScreen(browser)` in `OnAfterCreated` method:

```cpp
void SimpleHandler::OnAfterCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();
  
  makeBrowserWindowFullScreen(browser);
}
```

**Update**

An alternative implementation of `makeBrowserWindowFullscreen` that gets the window maximized by sending a `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` message could be this one:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#define _NET_WM_STATE_ADD 1

void makeBrowserWindowFullscreen(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
  auto xDisplay = cef_get_xdisplay();
  auto xWindow = browser->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle();

  Atom wm_state = XInternAtom(xDisplay, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
  Atom wm_fullscreen = XInternAtom(xDisplay, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", False);

  XEvent ev = {0};

  ev.type = ClientMessage;
  ev.xclient.window = xWindow;
  ev.xclient.message_type = wm_state;
  ev.xclient.format = 32;
  ev.xclient.data.l[0] = _NET_WM_STATE_ADD;
  ev.xclient.data.l[1] = wm_fullscreen;
  ev.xclient.data.l[2] = 0;

  XSendEvent(xDisplay, DefaultRootWindow(xDisplay), False, SubstructureNotifyMask | SubstructureRedirectMask, &ev);
  XFlush(xDisplay);
}
```